# Create a query/report to connect table a and b but must remove siffixes from b to perform the connection

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have been struggling with this for a while but cannot determine the best way to create my query.  I am running my test query in PL/SQL Developer and my Database is Oracle 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0.

I have two part number tables ‘a’ and ‘b’.  Table ‘a’ is an Inventory part table and table ‘b’ is a sales part table.  I am trying to create a report that will query for additional field data on the ‘a’ table based on a part number in the ‘b’ table.  Unfortunately there is not a 1:1 part number relationship between the two tables.  The part number in the b table contains a part number+fixed list of suffixes that must be removed before the lookup can occur.  Note: The suffixes are not currently in a separate table but can be done if needed.

List of Suffixes:  -AR, -BR, -EU, -JP, -LA, -NA, -OZ, -SA, -UK, -W, -AR1, -AR, -TNX01-OZ, -TNZ01, -TNZ02-OZ, -TNZ02

```
Select    a.part_no a_part_no,
          b.catalog_no b_part_no,
          a.CF$_PART_FAMILY part_family
From      inventory_part_cfv a,
          sales_part b
Where     b.catalog_no = a.part_no (+)
```

Current Output:

```
a_PART_NO       b_PART_NO               PART_FAMILY
E-100BTX-FX-05  E-100BTX-FX-05          E-100-05
                E-100BTX-FX-05-AR    
                E-100BTX-FX-05-BR    
                E-100BTX-FX-05-EU    
                E-100BTX-FX-05-JP    
                E-100BTX-FX-05-LA    
                E-100BTX-FX-05-NA    
                E-100BTX-FX-05-OZ    
                E-100BTX-FX-05-SA    
                E-100BTX-FX-05-UK    
MIL-S8TA        MIL-S8TA                MIL-S8T
                MIL-S8TA-W   
S3280           S3280                   x3280
                S3280-AR     
                S3280-AR1    
SBFFG1040-105   SBFFG1040-105           xBFFG
                SBFFG1040-105-TNZ01  
                SBFFG1040-105-TNZ01-OZ   
                SBFFG1040-105-TNZ02  
                SBFFG1040-105-TNZ02-OZ
```

Needed Output:

```
a_PART_NO       b_PART_NO               PART_FAMILY
E-100BTX-FX-05  E-100BTX-FX-05          E-100-05
                E-100BTX-FX-05-AR       E-100-06
                E-100BTX-FX-05-BR       E-100-07
                E-100BTX-FX-05-EU       E-100-08
                E-100BTX-FX-05-JP       E-100-09
                E-100BTX-FX-05-LA       E-100-10
                E-100BTX-FX-05-NA       E-100-11
                E-100BTX-FX-05-OZ       E-100-12
                E-100BTX-FX-05-SA       E-100-13
                E-100BTX-FX-05-UK       E-100-14
MIL-S8TA        MIL-S8TA                MIL-S8T
                MIL-S8TA-W              MIL-S8T
S3280           S3280                   x3280
                S3280-AR                x3281
                S3280-AR1               x3282
SBFFG1040-105   SBFFG1040-105           xBFFG
                SBFFG1040-105-TNZ01     xBFFG
                SBFFG1040-105-TNZ01-OZ  xBFFG
                SBFFG1040-105-TNZ02     xBFFG
                SBFFG1040-105-TNZ02-OZ  xBFFG
```

Comment: You appear to have an ineffective model for your desired output. For example why would output 'E-100BTX-FX-05, E-100BTX-FX-05, E-100-06' be excluded and 'E-100BTX-FX-05, E-100BTX-FX-05, E-100-05' included? Perhaps if you provided DDL and data in your question (or use SQLFiddle) it might be more clear. It appears as if your part_family field is not dependent upon the key.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I used Excel to populate my "Needed Output" and it messed up my desired output.

Comment: The desired output should be as follows.  Note: I added another column called b_catalog_type which is a field in the sales_part database that hopefully will make things a bit clearer. For the rows in the b_part_no column with a b_catalog_type=Package Part, I want to remove the suffix (example –BR from E-100BTX-FX-05-BR so I can query the related data (part_family) that is only available in the Inventory_Part Table with part_no=E-100BTX-FX-05.  There is not an Inventory Part number=E-100BTX-FX-05-BR.

Comment: a_PART_NO       b_PART_NO               b_catalog_type  PART_FAMILY
E-100BTX-FX-05  E-100BTX-FX-05          Inventory Part  E-100-05
                E-100BTX-FX-05-AR       Package Part    E-100-05
                E-100BTX-FX-05-BR       Package Part    E-100-05